# Cypress "have.attr" with regular expressions

Tags: cypress

In Cypress I can match an attribute's value by exact text like this:

```js
cy.get("my-element")
  .should("have.attr", "title", "Exact title")
```

But, is there a way to match the attribute's value by a substring or a regular expression? something like:

```js
cy.get("my-element")
  .should("have.attr", "title", /Partial title/)
```

So far, this is the best I have:

```js
cy.get("my-element")
  .should("have.attr", "title")
  .then(title => expect(title).to.match(/Partial title/));
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Per [the Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Syntax), `have.attr` comes from [`chai-jquery`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-jquery):

> #### `attr(name[, value])`
>
> Assert that the first element of the selection has the given attribute, using `.attr()`. Optionally, assert
>   a particular value as well. The return value is available for
>   chaining.
>
> ```js
> $('#header').should.have.attr('foo');
> expect($('body')).to.have.attr('foo', 'bar');
> expect($('body')).to.have.attr('foo').match(/bar/);
> ```

It only takes an exact value for the attribute directly. However, because the return value changes the subject, you can use *chaining* as also shown in the Cypress docs:

> ```js
> cy
>   .get('nav')                          // yields <nav>
>   .should('be.visible')                // yields <nav>
>   .should('have.css', 'font-family')   // yields 'sans-serif'
>   .and('match', /serif/)
> ```

In your case that would be

```js
cy.get("my-element")
  .should("have.attr", "title")
  .and("match", /Partial title/);
```

Comment: Instead of `.and("match", /Partial title/);` one could use `.and("contain", 'Partial title');`, too. This way you don't need a regex.