# Check for approximate attribute value in cypress test

Tags: javascript, testing, svg, integration-testing, cypress

I have written the following Cypress test to test an SVG element in my Angular app:

```
it("should have the right size", () => {
  cy.get(".rectangle")
    .first()
    .should("have.attr", "width", "80")
    .and("have.attr", "height", "60");
});
```

Unfortunately, the value of `width` and `height` can slightly vary. So I should rather allow for some small deviation.

**What is the recommended, shortest and/or most elegant way to do that?**

Comment: The usual escape hatch is [`should`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Should-callback).

Comment: Sorry, the first "and" in my code example was a left-over from an originally larger test. I fixed it. The point of my question is the comparison with e.g. 80, where I want to allow something like 70-90.

Comment: But you can still use the callback form to get the element. If you were only asserting on one attribute you could chain into the attribute (using the two-arg form, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57736128/3001761) but to do both you'd need the element.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, I see! Now I managed to derive a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66016581/3419103) that works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I derived the following solution from [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s comment, based on the [should-callback](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Should-callback) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57736128/3419103):

```
it("should have the right size", () => {
  cy.get(".rectangle")
    .first()
    .should(($rect) => expect(+$rect.attr("width")).to.be.closeTo(80, 10))
    .and(($rect) => expect(+$rect.attr("height")).to.be.closeTo(60, 10));
});
```

Alternatively, we can group both expectations into a single function:

```
it("should have the right size", () => {
  cy.get(".rectangle")
    .first()
    .should(($rect) => {
      expect(+$rect.attr("width")).to.be.closeTo(80, 10);
      expect(+$rect.attr("height")).to.be.closeTo(60, 10);
    });
});
```