# In Cypress, how do you wait for an input field to have (any) value?

Tags: cypress

I have an input element that eventually gets a value. How do I wait until it gets a value?

I tried this:

```
cy.get('#myInput').should('have.value');
```

But it ends up with this error:

```
Timed out retrying after 10000ms: expected '<input#myInput>' to have value undefined, but the value was 'my value'
```

I know I can pass in the expected value as a second parameter, but I don't know what it will be. I just need to wait until it has *any* value.

Comment: Could you give some context - where does that value come from, what's the input used for?

Comment: The form does some initialization stuff and then auto-populates some fields. I effectively just need to wait for this initialization to be complete, so waiting for one of the fields to have a value is a good way to do that.

Comment: What "stuff"? Please [edit] the question. I'm wondering why (and really _whether_) the value is completely unknown. [`have.value`](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-jquery/#valuevalue) doesn't chain, so I don't think you can do something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/57736128/3001761.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. Here's how to wait for an input field to have a value:

```
cy.get('#muInput').should('not.have.value', undefined)
```