# How to assert value of attribute?

Tags: attributes, cypress

In a Cypress test, I'd like to assert that a given attribute exists on the page with a given value.
The following works, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

```js
cy.get('[data-page-id]').invoke('attr', 'data-page-id').should('eq', 'signupPage')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress "have.attr" with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57736076/cypress-have-attr-with-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can directly assert the attribute and value in one go like this [example](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Assert-the-href-attribute-is-equal-to-users)

```js
cy.get('[data-page-id]').should('have.attr', 'data-page-id', 'signupPage')
```

Answer (score 9):

This is equivalent

```js
cy.get('[data-page-id="signupPage"]')
```

since `.get()` has a built-in assertion for all parts of the selector.

Comment: Thanks. This works but I've chosen to go with one of the other answers because the error message will display the value of the attribute if it exists but has the wrong value.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is a bit verbose, what you have done is the recommended way to perform an assertion on an attribute.