# How to check element value to only 2 decimal places

Tags: cypress

I am checking that a password entry location has an underline and I want to check that underlines properties such as its height.

Results keep coming in like this:

```
expected '<div.mat-form-field-underline.ng-tns-c55-42.ng-star-inserted>' to have CSS property 'height' with the value '2.0001628398895268px', but the value was '2.0001628398895264px'
```

I do not really care that it is out by such a small margin, does anyone know how I can make it check that only the first 2 decimal places are correct (i.e. "2.00")?

```javascript
cy.get('.mat-card-content > mat-form-field:nth-of-type(2) div.mat-form-field-underline').then(newPasswordUnderline => {
        
    cy.wrap(newPasswordUnderline).should('have.css','height','2.0001628398895268px')
    
})
```

Comment: I'd imagine something like `.should('have.css', 'height').and('be.close.to', x)` would work - similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57736128/3001761, those assertions change the subject.

Comment: Unfortunately that comes back with "The chainer close was not found"

Comment: Well I was close to it https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_closeto

Comment: In fact you're getting a string, so you can use a regex exactly as I show there - `have.attr` and `have.css` have the same source and behaviour.